# Extract from git last pushed branch name

Tags: git, branch

I have to find out (from command line) the name (only the name) of the last pushed branch.

I have found some command like:

```
git rev-name                                       --> have the last id and name
git log --pretty="%H" --decorate --graph  -n 1     --> have the last id
```

But I'm not able to put all together and have only the name.

I need it because in a openshift/jenkins pipeline I want to trigger a build and construct a pod with the branch name.

I think I'm not so far. Or maybe there are better commands.

Can you help me to figure out the name of the last pushed branch?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git log -1 --pretty="format:%D" | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $3}'`